# Frattini subgroup of a quotient

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, frattini-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group. The Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ is the intersection all proper maximal subgroups.

If $K \lhd G$ is a normal subgroup, then it is easy to see that $\Phi(G) K/K \leq \Phi(G/K)$ as subgroups of $\Phi(G/K)$.

**Question:** What's an example of a finite $G$ such that this inclusion is strict; that is, such that $\Phi(G) K/K \neq \Phi(G/K)$?

Comment: What you have written does not make sense. $\Phi(G)K$ is a subgroup of $G$, but $\Phi(G/K)$ is a subgroup of $G/K$, so neither can  be contained in the other. You probably mean $\Phi(G)K/K$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Thanks, I fixed the notation.

Comment: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/F5.html

Comment: Derek's comment is not fixed in your question.

Answer (score 3):

As written in the comments, the [$F_5$ group](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/F5.html) given by the presentation

$F_5 := \langle a,b \ | \ a^5=b^4=1, bab^{-1}=a^3 \rangle$

is a counterexample. It has a trivial Frattini subgroup, but it has the cyclic group  $C_{4}$ as a quotient, which has a non-trivial Frattini subgroup given by $2C_{4} \leq C_{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another counter-example: let $n\ge2$ and $q$ be a prime power. Then $\mathrm{PGL}_n(q)$ has trivial Frattini subgroup. Indeed, the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(q)$ of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}g&x\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ where $g\in\mathrm{GL}_{n-1}(q)$, $x\in\mathbb F_q^n$, and $a\in\mathbb F_q^\times$ (i.e., the stabilizer of a line in $\mathbb F_q^n$) form a maximal subgroup. But the intersection of its conjugates consists of matrices $A\in\mathrm{GL}_n(q)$ which preserves *every* line in $\mathbb F_q^n$, which must be scalar multiplication. But scalars are killed under the surjection $\mathrm{GL}_n(q)\to\mathrm{PGL}_n(q)$.

On the other hand, $\mathrm{PGL}_n(q)$ has a quotient $\mathbb F_q^\times/(\mathbb F_q^\times)^n$, descended from $\det\colon\mathrm{GL}_n(q)\to\mathbb F_q^\times$. With a clever choice of $q$ and $n$ (e.g., $q=5$ and $n=4$), $\mathbb F_q^\times/(\mathbb F_q^\times)^n$ will have non-trivial Frattini subgroup.